# SSH pm2: command not found

Tags: ssh, pm2

When I run this command from my local machine...

```
ssh user@123.456.789.255 "pm2 reload all"
```

I get this error...

```
pm2: command not found
```

Running the command in the remote machine works fine, so it's not a pathing issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to run the nvm to get it going first

`ssh user@123.456.789.255 "source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && pm2 reload all"`

Comment: Niiiiiiiice! Can you please explain why `~/.nvm/nvm.sh` is required?

Comment: sets up the environment so you can execute the command.